# Unique VM Server Identifier in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I need a unique identifier for each VM I run my script on. It needs to always be the same on the same server...

Have tried this:

```
import uuid

print('Serial', uuid.UUID(int=uuid.getnode()))
```

And I get:

`00000000-0000-0000-0000-de2b88079033` for `VM 1`

`00000000-0000-0000-0000-de2b88079009` for `VM 2`

---

While running just `uuid.getnode()` I get: `244278547157043`.

It's a different number for the second VM.

---

1. Why is it not a full UUID (`00000000-0000-0000-0000`)?
2. Is it truly unique, and will it ever change for as long as I have
   this VM?
3. Is it possible to just get the last part `de2b88079009`?
4. And on a bare-metal server will it be the whole UUID or just the last
   part like here?
5. Which method of the two is better?

Comment: `UUID.getnode` is returning "the hardware address of the server", which should (a) be unique and (b) should remain the same for the lifetime of the server.

Comment: @larsks How about `uuid.UUID(int=uuid.getnode())`?

Comment: You're just converting the result of `getnode` into hexadecimal, so the same thing applies.

Comment: @larsks Okay. Thx.

Comment: This [UUID article](https://pynative.com/python-uuid-module-to-generate-universally-unique-identifiers/) might be a good source answers to your questions.